# Алгоритм Кнута-Морриса-Пратта

Tags: java, алгоритм

Привет. Объясните, пожалуйста. Я уже очень много источников перечитал, но так и не понял.
Алгоритм КМП использует префикс-функцию (что это, как она работает, реализацию - я все это понял). Я не понял сам алгоритм КМП: что он делает, в чем смысл, зачем он нужен? Ведь у нас есть префикс функция, по которой мы можем определить, на какой позиции в строке нашелся искомый образец.

Вот тут нашел реализацию на Java: https://sites.google.com/site/indy256/algo/kmp_matcher
И мне не понятно это:

```
public static int kmpMatcher(String s, String pattern) {
int m = pattern.length();
if (m == 0)
  return 0;
int[] p = prefixFunction(pattern);
for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
  for (; ; k = p[k - 1]) {
    if (pattern.charAt(k) == s.charAt(i)) {
      if (++k == m)
        return i + 1 - m;
      break;
    }
    if (k == 0)
      break;
  }
return -1;
}
```

`int[] p = prefixFunction(pattern);` - какой смысл выполнять префикс-функцию для образца?

Answer (score 2):

Вычисление префикс-функции образца позволит избежать лишних сравнений.

Я как-то писал [статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/191454/), в которой старался понятным языком объяснить принцип работы алгоритма. Надеюсь, она поможет Вам внести ясность в понимание алгоритма.

Comment: Что именно непонятно? В "наивном" алгоритме образец перемещается по шаблону на постоянный шаг, равный 1. В КМП, используя префикс-функцию, мы можем перемещаться на большие шаги, гарантируя, что вхождение строки не будет пропущено.

Comment: @thejadefalcon, разумеется, в тривиальных случаях, когда образец состоит из разных символов, КМП будет работать даже медленнее "наивного" алгоритма. Но если образец имеет префикс-функцию, не состоящую из одних нулей, алгоритм будет работать быстрее за счет минимизации количества сравнений.

Comment: @DarkGenius Вот вы всё отвечаете и отвечаете, но никак не объясните, почему делается префикс функция для образца а не для образец#строка?)

Comment: @thejadefalcon, потому что мы перемещаем образец по строке. Вы понимаете, для начала, примитивный алгоритм поиска подстроки? В нем мы сначала проверяем сопоставление образца и части строки, начиная с первого символа, затем со второго и т.д., пока вся строка будет пройдена. В случае нетривиальной префикс-функции образца мы избежим лишних сравнений, поскольку сможем сдвигать образец не на 1 символ, а на несколько.

Comment: Извините.. но *Не понято*

Comment: @thejadefalcon, если рассмотрите вот такой случай:

      str = "aaaaaaaab"; pattern = "aaab";

то все станет ясно.

Сначала мы синхронно движемся по символам `str[i++]` и `pattern[k++]`. При `i = k = 3` обнаружим, что символы не равны и уменьшим `k` на 1 (смотрим на `pattern[2] = 'a'`). 

Вот тут у нас начнется, по сути, цикл (он неявно отражается в программе), поиска "ab" в str. На каждом его шаге мы будем увеличивать `i` и `k`, убеждаться, что 'b' != 'a', уменьшать `к` и повторять этот цикл, пока не наткнемя на `str[8] == pattern[3]` ('b' == 'b').

Все. Надеюсь, смог объяснить.

Answer (score 1):

К примеру, строка S=123123123, мы ищем вхождение сроки n=123123.
Если идти в лоб, то мы в цикле будем каждый раз смещаться по строке S на 1 и брать ее срез длине строке n и производить сравнение.

Однако не трудно заметить, что в данном случае, после того как мы нашли первое вхождение, нам необходимо сместится всего на 3 и начать сравнение с 4 позиции в строке - вот на этом и построен данный алгоритм.

Answer (score 1):

Префикс-функция (`prefixFunction()`) **транслирует** строковый образец в представление (массив индексов в строковом образце), удобное для быстрого определения, *находится ли целый образец* в данном месте строки.

Смотрите, `kmpMatcher()` в цикле перебирает все позиции `s`, и если в этой позиции присутствует образец, то возвращает ее (результат -- *FOUND*).

А если бы нам было нужно искать один и тот же образец во многих строках, то было бы выгодней вычислить prefixFunction один раз и передавать ее результат вместе с проверяемой строкой в модифицированный `kmpMatcher(String s, int [] pattern)`.

**Обновление**

Да, в самом деле. Я теперь тоже не понимаю.

--

Кажется, понял.  В соответствии с [описанием  в вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B0) (просто и доходчиво) при несовпадении очередного символа строки мы начнем новые сравнения **не обязательно с первого** символа образца.

Именно `p[]` (его вычисляет prefixFunction) определяет, с какого.

**Обновление 2**

Для экономии памяти. Представьте строку размером 100 мегабайт и образец в 100 байт.

Вы предлагаете вычислять префикс-функцию для 100 MB?

Comment: Неужели нет ответа на мой вопрос

Comment: Ну так опять же. Зачем вообще сравнивать строку с образцом, если префикс функция для образец#строка все уже сделала сама? :)

Comment: @avp Тогда теперь не пойму, как КМП использует префикс-функцию. Ну вот. Thebrownfoxjumpoverdog. Ищется образец "jump". Выполняется префикс-функция для "jump" = 0 0 0 0. И как это поможет?